# How to update geospatial data via laravel 8 mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I'm trying to update geospatial data in mongodb using laravel version 8, while login i've to update long,lat in geospatial coordinates in mongo database, data how it stored in the database is shown below, here "point" is field name of geospatial coordinates.

```
 point:Object
      type:"Point"
        coordinates: Array
          0:122.00084
          1:37.4219983
```

> This is how it stored in database
> i'm passing the value in update query as follows

```php
$date = Carbon::now();
$timestamp = $date->getPreciseTimestamp(3);
$updateData = ['user_token' => $token,
    'update_at' => $timestamp,
    'point' => ['type' => 'Point', 'coordinates' => [$long, $lat]]

];
 
$q = Post::where('user_id', $userID)->update($updateData);
```

it throws an error "exception":

"MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException",

```json
{
    "message": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: \"261058c2f2576b4f72365d3ee1d5a03d\", user_id: \"7c2d166e170a6d8457ca16424892b05b\", name: \"qwer\", profile_pic: \"\", email: \"mailid@mail.com\", password: \"e10adc3949b234a59a2134bbe56e0572134f20f883e\", city: \"ind\", state: \"IN\", zip: \"600000\", country: \"India\", user_token: \"asdfadsf\", point: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ \"-122.084\", \"37.4219983\" ] }, is_active: true, verifiy_key: \"168d224a36785f00e28e232068qerweadcac8f1fsdfcbeade5f643cbd2e683548fd069200423749b\", email_status: true, is_not",
    "exception": "MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\BulkWriteException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/ce5/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Update.php",
    "line": 200,
}
```

Comment: You don't need to include an entire stack trace in your question, especially one that isn't formatted properly. I'd expect you'll have to use raw statements unless you have a database driver that can handle geospatial columns.

Comment: Or are you using the `jessegers/laravel-mongodb` package, which *does* have support for geo columns?

Comment: yes, i'm using jessegers package.